# How to get the HTML output of a drupal node having php code?

Tags: php, drupal

I have a node with the following content (input mode: php code):

```
this is a <?php echo "test" ?>
```

If I output node->body, the output is

```
this is a <?php echo "test" ?>
```

What I want is:

```
this is a test
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

(I don't want all the default divs and other structural stuff coming with it when I call node_view)

Comment: do you have a WYSIWYG editor enabled? Because that will escape the input, resulting not in PHP, but in HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable (shipped with core) "php.module", which comes with an input-formatter, PHP-filter. That filter allows you to insert php as you mention in nodes. And will eval() that for you on output.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't use the php filter that's needed to do something like this. The result is your code is escaped.

On a random drupal install I just tested:

```
This is a <?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

Outputs

```
This is a test
```

When I view the node.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal, to display html output of a node which have 'PHP Filter' you can do this

`echo php_eval(node->body);`

Answer (score -1):

You could output

```
eval($node->body); // be sure what you are evaling
```

Comment: Drupal should already 'eval' it, really no need toeval it yourself, in fact, chances are this will both horribly break and thta this opens up severe security holes.

Comment: I don't know if Drupal evals a html string before outputting, I would not see why. My response is the PHP solution of what Niyaz wanted.